# Как получить прямой доступ к памяти внешнего устройства?

Tags: linux, внешние-устройства

Что я подразумеваю под прямым доступом к памяти? Да возьму хотя бы стандартный телефон в качестве примера. Т е, подключаем телефон (неважно какой, Xiaomi, iPhone...), а на хосте Linux/Unix мы получаем устройства в `/dev`:

```
 ~ # ls /dev
mmcblk0
mmcblk0p1
...
mmcblk0p30
 ~ # ls /dev/block/by-name -l
...
userdata -> /dev/mmcblk0p45
...
```

Вместо привычного Android устройства, думаю, логичнее подставить какое-нибудь небольшое устройство - кнопочный телефон, какую-нибудь камеру, или даже флэш-память мат. платы, куда записан БИОС. Вопрос: а как вообще (и можно ли) такое провернуть? Тогда хотя бы через dd можно сдампить разделы и в них покопаться).

Comment: JTAG — твой друг, не говоря уже о том, что это не всегда простая задача добраться до него на **продуктовом** устройстве.

Comment: JTAG и UART это скорее халявная консоль - и то, тут нужно Orange Pi... Ладно бы ещё ttyUSB0 - я бы такое с радостью прокинул в свою мобилу, отлавливать бутлупы). Но я говорю о доступе к памяти, а не халявной консоли...

Comment: @RandomDice779 как выглядит устройство?)

Comment: меня интересует более общая и техническая часть...

Comment: из общего только отпаивать флешку.или репак обновления

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, в современных устройствах это так не работает.

Дело даже не в том, что производители устройств, в среднем, против того, чтобы кто то "покопался" в их прошивке. И даже не в том, что Вы хотите получить прямой доступ не к застывшему слепку памяти, а к участкам оперативной памяти, на которых одновременно бегут разные процессы в исследуемом устройстве, которые могут изменть эту самую память.

В современных устройствах каждый "раздел" (а "раздел" создётся, буквально, по каждому чиху: приложеньку поставил - под неё создан новый логический раздел) представлет собой отдельную файловую систему, которая может быть зашифрована с использованием ключей, которые прошиты в системе аппаратно.

Мне кажется, что единственную пользу, которую я могу принести своим ответом - это дать Вам ссылку на статью об [основах загрузки на ARM](https://habr.com/ru/company/aladdinrd/blog/338806/)

Comment: Статья интересная, почитал с удовольствием. Но, кажется, вы меня не совсем поняли. Во1, тот же BIOS (да, Legacy BIOS) можно прошить, если не из хоста - то через флешку с FreeDOS/очень старой Windows (в т ч пресловутый MS-DOS). Во2, тот же aboot (иногда обозначается abl) запросто вынесен в /dev/block, оттуда его можно с root-ом перезаписать (гипотетически).

Comment: И в3, а ведь ОС, загрузчик и т д как-то же зашивают в устройства, даже если загрузчик ищется по определенному сектору памяти (да-да, опять Legacy BIOS), либо boot раздел представлен не [монтируемым] разделом, а бинарной склейкой, вызываемой "напрямую" (Android boot.img/recovery.img)

Comment: Извините, конечно, я мог Вас понять не так. я имел дело с компами (ну, с теми, на котрых мы работаем) и со специализированными контроллерами. я хотя в них есть аналогии с "биосом" - но, вообще говоря, там ВСЕ не так. Ваша идея насчет "прямого доступа к памяти" - клёвая, но, мне кажется, она будет хорошо работать в пределах достаточно старых OS. В современных - с памятью творится ТАКОЕ (компрессия памяти и т.п.), что особого преимущества даже прямой доступ к памяти не даст. Ну, получите Вы ядро в не-пожатом виде. Отладка всего этого барахла без исходников - это всё равно такой квест...

Comment: А вообще, если Вам кажется, что мой ответ бесполезен - напишите в комментариях, я его уберу. 
И не обижусь :-) Возможно, найдётся кто то, кто сможет ответить более содержательно.

Comment: Да, мне главное - получить доступ к памяти (именно постоянной памяти, флешке, mmc...) как к обычной флешке или диску, хотя бы read-only. Далее "в лоб" дампить через dd - и все) Правда, mmcblk0rpmb так не сдампишь - даже интересно, как работает защита RPMB раздела...

Comment: Первая здравая мысль - а не делается ли ТАКОЕ  каким нибудь модулем ядра? который, соответственно, надо запустить на "атакуемой" системе?

Comment: во1, мне надо подключить внешнее устройство как флешку. Во2, а если уж это не Unix/Linux?

Comment: @S.H. зашифрованных разделов не видел ни разу. подписанные для защиты от модификации - да, но зашифрованных нет)

Answer (score 1):

В случае роутеров и камер нужно найти пины UART и подключиться туда адаптером. При подключении питания прервать запуск и у вас будет U-BOOT или аналог на этой консоли. Прошивку выкачать оттуда обычно сложно потому как производитель хоть немного защищается, а вот записать новую можно через z-modem или tftp легко. Заливай туда более продвинутую версию загрузчика и можно читать.

Чтоб прочитать содержимое флешки на камере можно отпаять её и считать программатором. Если паять не вариант, то нужно найти обновление прошивки и перепаковать его добавив в автозагрузку telnet без пароля.

Для телефонов обычно нужно найти точку на плате и замкнуть её на корпус при подключении питания. Телефон будет в режиме прошивки и через специальную программу можно вычитать и записать всё